# C# SQL connection OpenAsync is not asynchronous

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, sqlconnection

I'm trying to open a connection to an SQL server asynchronously, so as not to tie up the UI thread. But I've found that the call to `connection.OpenAsync()` does not return until the connection has been opened, exactly as with `connection.Open()`.

This code reproduces the issue:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.UserID = "sa";
    builder.Password = "1234";
    builder.DataSource = "192.168.1.254\\SQLEXPRESS";
    builder.InitialCatalog = "MyDatabase";
    builder.PersistSecurityInfo = true;

    DbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);

    Console.WriteLine("about to connect");

    Task connection_task = connection.OpenAsync();

    Console.WriteLine("started");

    while (!connection_task.IsCompleted && !connection_task.IsFaulted && !connection_task.IsCanceled)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("busy");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("done");
}
```

In this case, `192.168.1.254` is non-existent. The message `about to connect` appears immediately, but then while waiting for the connection to time out nothing happens, then after the connection times out the messages `started` and `done` appear at the same time. I would expect that the message `started` would appear immediately after the message `about to connect`, then the message `done` would appear later once the connection has timed out.

I'm guessing that I'm doing something wrong with the returned `Task`, but the Microsoft page on [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap) certainly implies that I should simply be able to call the `OpenAsync()` method and the returned `Task` will be running asynchronously, instead of the operation taking place synchronously and tying up the calling thread until the `Task` completes.

Comment: I tried exactly this code and it behaves as expected, I get a load of "busy" before "done". This is a new console app in VS 2017 targetting .NET 4.6.1.

Comment: I'm targeting .NET 4.5 in MonoDevelop. I experience the same behaviour on Windows 10 and on Linux.

Comment: Also I get the same result as Adam, it prints "busy" a bunch of times, and then "done".

Comment: @Michael Ok so there we have a difference already. To me that seems like a bug in Mono, it doesn't yield the task when it hits a bit where it can register some sort of wait. `async` isn't concurrent, it'll run synchronously until something gives control back after registering with something like an IO completion port.

Comment: @AndyJ Not a syntax error, ADO.NET connections derived from `DbConnection`.

Comment: @AndyJ `SqlConnection` is a subclass of `DbConnection`. I'm using `DbConnection` here because the final version is supposed to support multiple backends.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Could you elaborate exactly what the issue with Mono is? I have tested the compiled result on Windows 10 with the .NET framework that's installed by default with Windows 10 and I get exactly the same behaviour. I would be very surprised if Mono does not implement asynchronous operations correctly as this is a core language feature.

Comment: @MichealJohnson Not specifically, but I would first be investigating Mono (issues of github and whatnot, chat rooms) because the same code functions correctly on regular .NET. The bug I allude to could be limited to `OpenAsync` on `SqlConnection`. The fact you also get it on regular .NET now confuses me, I don't. What version of the compiler are you using?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth When I say that I test on .NET, I mean that I compile using Mono and then run on .NET. Running `mcs --version` gives me `Mono C# compiler version 4.2.1.0`, assuming that this is the same compiler that MonoDevelop uses.

Comment: @MichealJohnson Any chance you can provide the IL that produces?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth How do I do that?

Comment: @MichealJohnson I use dotPeek from JetBrains, but there is also ILSpy. Point it at your dll / exe.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Try this: https://pastebin.com/4WuWSGnc Produced using `monodis` (Mono disassembler). I'd be interested to compare with the disassembly of your .NET version.

Comment: @MichealJohnson Almost identical: https://pastebin.com/JJkkj62q

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Yep, I agree. The only thing that I noticed was that you were setting `builder.ConnectTimeout`, but this doesn't make any difference for me.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Here's my binary: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RC6IIbFx0XxtbU5m7Absqa_6QJIeHyTY/view?usp=sharing Can I try yours?

Comment: @MichealJohnson That works for me... got lots of "busy" before "done". Mine is here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgNYZnIpll12l9gYUT-Pcx1MFNcvUQ

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth OK this is *really* embarrassing. I tried your version on Windows 10 and it works. Then I tried my version again on Windows 10 and it works. Then I tried the original version (rather than the simplified test case) on Windows 10 and it works. Even though I *swear* I tried both my original version and my simplified test case on Windows 10 before I posted the question. Weird...

Comment: I also tried your binary on Mono, and I have the same issue as with my binary. So now I'm going to try to track down which version didn't work on Windows 10. Otherwise I'm going to assume it's a problem with the Mono runtime.

Comment: @MichealJohnson Might be worth trying older .NET runtimes on Windows too, or binaries compiled with older C# compilers. I'm fully up to date as this is my work PC.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth So it turns out that I had previously tested on Windows 10 with the MySQL backend rather than the Microsoft SQL one. So it seems that a) the Microsoft SQL backend does not support asynchronous connections on Mono but works fine on .NET, and b) the MySQL backend does not support asynchronous connections on any runtime.

Comment: @MichealJohnson Mystery solved :-)

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth No need to test with older .NET versions, I'm not targeting anything below .NET 4.5 on Windows 10. But if it works fine on .NET 4.5 on Windows 10 then I'm satisfied that it should work on any version that supports the required language/runtime/library features. But I'm going to have to look into a workaround for this anyway, as MySQL support is very important in my situation.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Yeah, sorry for wasting your time...

Comment: @MichealJohnson Not a waste, I'm glad we've got an answer.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth OK np then :-)

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that this is a bug in the Mono runtime and that the code works fine on Microsoft .NET. A similar bug also seems to be present with the MySQL .NET library (`MySql.Data`), which runs the task synchronously regardless of whether the Mono or the Microsoft .NET runtime is used.

EDIT: I've found a [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70111) for the issue with MySQL.

Comment: That bug isn't looking too likely to be fixed mate, it's been around for a while :-( Another SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978629/does-net-4-5s-async-feature-work-with-mysql-and-other-databases-too

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Yeah, doesn't look like it's going to be fixed soon. But it's OK, I think I've found a workaround for my particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try add  `Asynchronous Processing=True` or `Async=True` property to your connection string,

and add await to function call, like this : `await connection.OpenAsync();`

I hope this help you.

Comment: Setting `builder.AsynchronousProcessing = true` does not help. `await` makes the current thread wait for the task to finish; I would expect that *without* using `await` that I would get the expected behaviour, where the current thread continues without waiting for the task to finish.

Comment: This setting is a no-op in .NET 4.5 and above (which is being used, per the comments). Even if it wasn't, it enables only the use of the `.BeginXXX` methods (i.e. the "old" asynchronous model), which otherwise throw an exception, and should have no effect on the use of `async`/`await`.

Comment: `await` does not make the current thread wait for the task to finish, it makes the current thread go off and do something else (unless the task was already finished to begin with).