# What's wrong with my .NET core code, getting an error while making a database request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, mysql-connector

The error is occuring in the `getStores()` function:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>       ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>       Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'

```
  public class StoreController : Controller

{
    // dependency-injected
    private readonly MySqlConnection _connection;

    public StoreController(MySqlConnection mySqlConnection)
    {
        _connection = mySqlConnection;
    }
 // GET
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("home");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/stores")]
    public async Task getStores()
    {
        // open connection
        await _connection.OpenAsync();
        // execute query and get stores
        using var command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Stores", _connection);
        using var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
        {
            var value = reader.GetValue(0);
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the lifetime strategy you are using for injecting the connection?

Comment: Checkout this [link](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,61856,114976#msg-114976) and see if it helps. Post says the connection might have been closed due to inactivity or other reason.

Comment: Can you please add MySqlConnection code as well.

Comment: @Crowcoder Transient

Comment: Specifically what line of code blows up?

Comment: I think it's this one `await _connection.OpenAsync();`

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't debug and see exactly what line throws the exception, but now I question if you are really using transient lifetime. Can you show your ConfigureServices code?

Comment: `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            // register database connection
            services.AddTransient<MySqlConnection>(_ =>
                new MySqlConnection(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Default"]));
        } `

Comment: @Crowcoder i know exactly which line throws the exception it's `await _connection.OpenAsync();`

Comment: I think this is the bug that i'm running into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47456689/c-sharp-sql-connection-openasync-is-not-asynchronous

Comment: There are several examples of "async" apis that are not actually asynchronous. In fact, you never really have an absolute guarantee of asynchrony but that's a whole separate subject. Regardless of whether or not it runs asynchronously, it should not throw that exception. Does it behave differently if you don't use the async calls?

Comment: Oh, i know exactly what the issue is now, Mono is crashing, I'm getting a mono_crash.mem.blob

Comment: @Crowcoder yes it behaves the same way, i can't open the connection because Mono keeps crashing for some reason?

Comment: So you're not using .NET Core? Or do I have a serious lack of understanding of what Mono is?

Comment: No, I am using .NET core, it's just a bug that has been around for a while

Comment: Can you provide detailed methods of ` MySqlConnection`  for our reference? Using SqlConnection in core, you can add `ConnectionStrings` to the database in `appsetting.json`, and then use  `IConfiguration` dependency injection to call ConnectionStrings to connect to the database, please refer to:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/access-sql-server-database-in-net-core-console-application

Comment: Oh, i already resolved the issue, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Youssef  Could you tell us what the problem was and finally how you solved it. Just in case someone else gets the same problem. You can add an anwser to your own question.